# How to add values from nested hashTable values

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Below is my code. I would like to add then read individual values.

```
$ht = @{
    'Hcohesity01' = @{
        'Audit'  = 1
        'Block'  = 2
        'Change' = 3
        'percentage' = @{
        'server1'  = 4
        'server2'  = 5
        'server3' = 10
    }
    
    }
    'Hcohesity02' = @{
        'Audit'  = 1
        'Block'  = 2
        'Change' = 3
        'percentage' = @{
        'server1'  = 4
        'server2'  = 5
        'server3' = 10
    }
    
    }
}
$ht['Hcohesity02']['percentage']['server4'] = 20
foreach ( $value -in $ht['Hcohesity02']['percentage'].Values){
$server5 += $value
              }

$ht['Hcohesity02']['percentage']['server5'] =$server5
$ht['Hcohesity02']['percentage']
```

Below code is not working , any idea ?
foreach ( $value -in $ht['Hcohesity02']['percentage'].Values)

Comment: What do you expect to happen? It's unclear, not working doesn't give us much information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real mistake in your code is by writing `-in` in the foreach loop. That should have been just `in`.

Instead of using a loop to add-up the values, you can use a one-liner with `Measure-Object`:

```
$ht = @{
    'Hcohesity01' = @{
        'Audit'  = 1
        'Block'  = 2
        'Change' = 3
        'percentage' = @{
            'server1'  = 4
            'server2'  = 5
            'server3' = 10
        }
    }
    'Hcohesity02' = @{
        'Audit'  = 1
        'Block'  = 2
        'Change' = 3
        'percentage' = @{
            'server1'  = 4
            'server2'  = 5
            'server3' = 10
        }
    }
}

$ht['Hcohesity02']['percentage']['server4'] = 20

# instead of a foreach loop:
# $server5 = 0  # initialize
# foreach ( $value in $ht['Hcohesity02']['percentage'].Values) {
    # $server5 += $value
# }

# you can do this:
$server5 = ($ht['Hcohesity02']['percentage'].Values | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum

$ht['Hcohesity02']['percentage']['server5'] = $server5
$ht['Hcohesity02']['percentage']
```

Result:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                
server2                        5                                                                                                                                                    
server5                        39                                                                                                                                                   
server3                        10                                                                                                                                                   
server1                        4                                                                                                                                                    
server4                        20
```

<sup>If you don't like addressing the properties with the `[property]` syntax, you can also use dot notation as [hoppy7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71835360/9898643) showed in his answer:</sup>

```
$ht.'Hcohesity02'.'percentage'.Values  # and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not quite clear what you're trying to do.  If its just iterating through your foreach loop and assigning a value, you need to ditch the dash on "-in".  It should look like the below:

```
foreach ($value in $ht.Hcohesity02.percentage.Values)
{
    # do some stuff
}
```

Comment: very good ideas from here.